# Magento get Unique sku?

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using Marketplace in my website also some product have more then one seller. Even every seller have unique **SKU**

```
<?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
                $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res['mpassignproduct_id']);
                $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);     
                if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                   {   $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$assignproduct['sku']." </strong> <span>".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";

                   }
                } else {
                     $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a> <strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong> <span>".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span>&nbsp;</p>";
                      }


                    }
```

We used above code to `Model/saleslist.php` it's working find But in front end 
.phtml file i can't able to get unique sku?
How to get that Sku in front end file?

```
vieworder.phtml






<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table" summary="<?php echo $this->__('Items Ordered') ?>">
                    <col />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="30%"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
                            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
                             <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>

                            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Total Price') ?></th>
                            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Admin Commission') ?></th>
                            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Sub Total') ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection(); ?>
                    <?php $i = 0; ?>
                    <?php $_count = $_items->count(); ?>
                    <?php 
                    $subtotal = 0;
                    $shippingamount = 0;
                    $itemPrice = 0;
                    foreach ($_items as $_item){
                        $row_total = 0;
                        $available_seller_item = 0;
                        $seller_item_cost = 0;          
                        $orderid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                        $vendor_item_status=$this->getItemStatus($orderid,$_item->getProductId());                      
                        $seller_orderslist=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$customerid))
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$_item->getProductId()))
                                                     // ->addFieldToFilter('mageproprice',array('eq'=>$_item->getPrice()))
                                                     ->setOrder('mageorderid','DESC');
                        foreach($seller_orderslist as $seller_item){
                            $parentitem_falg = 0;
                            $available_seller_item = 1;
                            $seller_item_commission = $seller_item->getTotalcommision();
                            $shippingcharges = $seller_item->getShippingCharges();
                            $itemPrice = $seller_item->getMageproprice();
                        }
                        if($available_seller_item == 1){
                            $i++;
                            $seller_item_qty = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
                            $row_total=$itemPrice*$seller_item_qty;
                            $seller_item_cost = $row_total-$seller_item_commission;
                            $subtotal=$subtotal+$seller_item_cost;
                            $shippingamount = $shippingamount+$shippingcharges;

                            $result = array();
                            if ($options = $_item->getProductOptions()) {
                                if (isset($options['options'])) {
                                    $result = array_merge($result, $options['options']);
                                }
                                if (isset($options['additional_options'])) {
                                    $result = array_merge($result, $options['additional_options']);
                                }
                                if (isset($options['attributes_info'])) {
                                    $result = array_merge($result, $options['attributes_info']);
                                }
                            }
                            // for bundle product
                            $bundleitems = array_merge(array($_item), $_item->getChildrenItems());
                            $_count = count ($bundleitems);
                            $_index = 0;
                            $_prevOptionId = '';                            
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; ?>
                            <tbody class="myorder">
                                <!-- <tbody class="<?php echo $class = ($i%2 != 0)? 'odd':'even'?>"> -->
                                <?php
                                if($_item->getProductType()!='bundle'){
                                ?>
                                    <?php if($labl!=''){$pname=$_item->getName() .'(' .$labl. ')';} else{$pname=$_item->getName();} ?>
                                    <tr class="border" id="order-item-row-<?php echo $_item->getMageproid() ?>">
                                        <td>
                                            <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $pname;?></h3>

                                            <?php if($_options = $result): ?>
                                                <dl class="item-options">
                                                <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                                                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                                                    <?php if (!$this->getPrintStatus()): ?>
                                                        <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                                                        <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>>
                                                            <?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                                            <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                                            <div class="truncated_full_value">
                                                                <dl class="item-options">
                                                                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                                                                    <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                                                                </dl>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                        </dd>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <dd>
                                                            <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml( (isset($_option['print_value']) ? $_option['print_value'] : $_option['value']) )) ?>
                                                        </dd>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                </dl>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="sku">
                                            <?php echo $_item->getSku();?>

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getPrice(), true, false);?></td>

                                        <td class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($row_total, true, false);?></td>
                                        <td class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($seller_item_commission, true, false);?></td>
                                        <td class="row_total"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($seller_item_cost, true, false);?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php
                                }else{
                                ?>
                                <?php foreach ($bundleitems as $_bundleitem): ?>
                                    <?php
                                    $attributes_option = null;
                                    if ($_bundleitem instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item) {
                                        $options = $_bundleitem->getProductOptions();
                                    } else {
                                        $options = $_bundleitem->getOrderItem()->getProductOptions();
                                    }
                                    if (isset($options['bundle_selection_attributes'])) {
                                        $attributes_option =  unserialize($options['bundle_selection_attributes']);
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <?php if ($_bundleitem->getParentItem()): ?>
                                        <?php $attributes = $attributes_option ?>
                                        <?php if ($_prevOptionId != $attributes['option_id']): ?>
                                        <tr<?php if ($_bundleitem->getLastRow()) echo 'class="last"'; ?>>
                                            <td><div class="option-label"><?php echo $attributes['option_label'] ?></div></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php $_prevOptionId = $attributes['option_id'] ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <tr<?php echo (++$_index==$_count)?' class="border"':'' ?> id="order-item-row-<?php echo $_bundleitem->getId() ?>">
                                        <?php 
                                        if (!$_bundleitem->getParentItem()){?>
                                            <td><h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_bundleitem->getName()) ?></h3></td>
                                            <td class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getPrice(), true, false);?></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($row_total, true, false);?></td>
                                            <td class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($seller_item_commission, true, false);?></td>
                                            <td class="row_total"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($seller_item_cost, true, false);?></td>
                                        <?php
                                        } else{
                                            $_bundleitem_child_name ='';
                                            if ($attributes = $attributes_option){
                                                $_bundleitem_child_name =  sprintf('%d', $attributes['qty']) . ' x ' .$this->escapeHtml($_bundleitem->getName()) . " " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($attributes['price'], true, false);
                                            } else {
                                                $_bundleitem_child_name = $this->escapeHtml($_bundleitem->getName());
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            <td><div class="option-value"><?php echo $_bundleitem_child_name?></div></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td class="item_status">
                                                <span class="nobr">
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getQtyOrdered() > 0): ?>
                                                        <?php echo $this->__('Ordered'); ?>: <strong><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1 ?></strong><br />
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getQtyShipped() > 0): ?>
                                                        <?php echo $this->__('Shipped'); ?>: <strong><?php echo $_item->getQtyShipped()*1 ?></strong><br />
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getQtyCanceled() > 0): ?>
                                                        <?php echo $this->__('Canceled'); ?>: <strong><?php echo $_item->getQtyCanceled()*1 ?></strong><br />
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getQtyRefunded() > 0): ?>
                                                        <?php echo $this->__('Refunded'); ?>: <strong><?php echo $_item->getQtyRefunded()*1 ?></strong><br />
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <?php
                                        }?>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php
                                }?>
                            <!-- </tbody> -->
                        </tbody>
                            <?php 
                        }
                    }?>
```

Comment: is this seller login page? can you add more code like which collection you trying to get this mean in order item or seller product or else?

Comment: i tried your code it's not working is there any solution

Comment: add the answer passing the seller id and product id

Comment: @Kothari : You are going wrong way. This module are provided default functionality are you need.

Comment: @Abdul it's not a default functionality we customize based on Qaisar Satti

Comment: Above solution is not proper solution because your are also facing order, invoice,shipment & creadmemo view , email & pdf.

Comment: ok then how to add sku ? can you please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the `product id` to where

```
$customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();

<?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
                $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.product_id=?', $item->getProductId())->where('mpassignproduct.seller_id_id=?', $customerid);
                $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);     
                if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                   {   echo $assignproduct['sku']; 

                   }
                }
```

Comment: Where to pass product id

Comment: `$res['product_id']` here add your product id

Comment: i think this code not availble in above

Comment: no this is new code for getting product from `seller id` and `product id`

Comment: can you please update that code

Comment: it is updated just pass you product id where condition you will get

Comment: i can use this but still it's showing empty only

Comment: did you pass the product id?

Comment: How to pass and where to pass

Comment: can you paste more code that are related to this product sku?

Comment: Sorry i can't get it\

Comment: mean your page code where you want to display the sku.

Comment: View Order page seller can able to view order details there i want to display sku

Comment: can you paste the order code? and print_r(orderdata); what is in that loop

Comment: Order code means?

Comment: can you paste full file code and mention where you want to show sku

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: update the code try it and feedback me

Comment: Call To A Member Function GetProductId() On A Non-Object

Comment: print_r($seller_item); check what is output of that?

Comment: $_item this is the problem i got it. it's working thanks